# changing sizes of individual userform pages

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel multipage userform, and I would like the pages to be different sizes/height. I have tried the following code:

```
sub multipage1_change()
select case me.multipage1.value
case 0
Me.multipage1.height=500
case 1
Me.multipage1.height=600
case 2 
Me.multipage1.height=800
end sub
```

Unfortunately all that happens is the largest userform size is always visible and the smaller userform pages are simply overlaid onto it. Surely it is possible to have the different pages be different heights?

Comment: It's just the missing `End Select` :-)

Comment: Why not just use scrollbars on the larger pages and leave the control the same size?

Answer (score 1):

Double click on the MultiPage and import the below code. Make sure that you import the code on "Private Sub MultiPage1_Change" see below:

[image]

Try:

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()

Select Case MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Name
    Case "Page1": MultiPage1.Height = 500
    Case "Page2": MultiPage1.Height = 600
    Case "Page3": MultiPage1.Height = 800
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: nope, doesn't work. It's probably not possible. Thanks for trying

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. Unfortunately it won't let me accept or upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Index instead of MultiPage1.Value or TabFixedHeight instead of height.